# Prevent NGINX from reordering query paramaters

Tags: proxy, nginx

I've got an odd issue. Nginx is reordering query parameters in alphabetical order vs the order the request is.

For example, if I supply a URL of:

```
https://example.com/?a[]=c&a[]=a&a[]=b
```

I would expect the `$query_string` to be:

```
a[]=c&a[]=a&a[]=b
```

but I'm getting

```
a[]=a&a[]=b&a[]=c
```

We are using Nginx as a proxy to route all sorts of URLs/subdomains to different types of applications. Normally this wouldn't be an issue on most modern applications, but we are using some legacy applications (whose code we can't change) that break when the query isn't in the exact order it expects.

The current .conf for the proxying is pretty simple:

```
# Get the application private IP from the name #
map_hash_bucket_size 128;
map $host $task_url {
    include /etc/nginx/service-mappings.conf;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;

    if ($task_url = false) {
        return 404 "Service was not mapped.";
    }

    location ~ /(.*) {
        add_header X-QueryParams $1$is_args$args; # Is not outputting correct value
        add_header X-TaskUrl $task_url;
        proxy_pass http://$task_url/$1$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/service-mapper.log;
}
```

Comment: `$args` is a literal string of the parameters as they appear in the original request. Nginx does not change the order of the arguments. There must be some other effect you are observing.

Comment: You are very correct. We had query string organizing on in cloudflare. Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not the issue of Nginx.

We had `Query String Sort` enabled in CloudFlare.

We set up a page rule to disable this for just these domains and it worked.